# React.js syntax error exporting function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

Having a minor syntax error with react while exporting a default function

Here's the code:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function GamesList({games}) => {

    const emptyMessage = (
        <p>There are no game yet in your collection.</p>
    );

    const gamesList = (
        <p>games list</p>
    );

    return(
        <div>
            {games.length === 0 ? emptyMessage : gamesList}
        </div>

    );
}

GamesList.propTypes = {
    games: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
}
```

Specifically, this line is causing the problem:

```
export default function GamesList({games}) => {
```

Where the "=>" is.I'm getting an unexpected token error but if I remove it or change it slightly, I get a long list of other errors. Any suggestions? Still quite new at using react.js

Comment: Surely you can't use the function keyword and an arrow function at the same time? Does the error go away if you remove the function keyword?

Comment: removing 'function' produces the same error. Getting rid of the {} around games produces several more errors

Comment: Its not about react, it is about understanding ES6 Js. You mixed up things, pretty bad friend. First understand the concept :)

Comment: @MarkO'Hare what other errors do you get?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I'm getting a "TypeError: this.context.router.createHref is not a function" whenever I remove the "=>"

Comment: @MarkO'Hare Are you using react-router?

Comment: Yeah I am, could that be what's causing the error?

Comment: @Mark O'Hare Don't remove `ecmascript-6` tag. It is more relevant to the question than `reactjs`

Comment: @MarkO'Hare indeed it is. Can you try this: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/975#issuecomment-84268324 and fix your arrow function as suggested in the answers below

Comment: I just checked my package.json file and I'm actually using react-router-dom 4.0.0-beta.5. Is this a similar issue with that release?

Comment: @MarkO'Hare Could you please also put the code where you use react router?

Comment: You do need to drop the '=>' from the function. The other errors you are getting are down to React Router. If you're following the tutorial I think you are, the react router API in that tut has since been changed, check the documentation and replace <Match> with <Switch> and <Route>

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing function declaration and arrow function syntax here. Drop the `=>`:

```
export default function GamesList({games}) {
    const emptyMessage = …;
    const gamesList = …;
    return …;
}
```

Comment: As I said in my question, doing that causes a long list of errors. Specifically "TypeError: this.context.router.createHref is not a function". Could the problem be elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't appear to be in the code you posted. The syntax error just prevented the compiler from reaching those problems.

Answer (score 0):

You want the following syntax;

```js
import React from ‘react’;

const GamesList = ({games}) => (
 <div>My Logic</div>
);

export default GamesList;
```

Comment: Doesn't  make any difference. I'm getting a "TypeError: this.context.router.createHref is not a function" with a long list of errors when doing that. Thinking I might have missed something somewhere else

Comment: Yeah that looks like its something your doing with react-router